# Radio Button in Selenium with Java

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to check if radio button is selected or not but I'm unable to find the xpath for radio button selection check in selenium with Java.

I'm trying this code to see if "one way" checkbox is selected then the browser should select the two way check box. But everytime when I run the code it only see that "one way" checkbox is selected and else condition is called. Here is what I'm doing to check the condition.

```
WebElement radioElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='css-1dbjc4n']"));
        boolean selectState = radioElement.isSelected();
        System.out.println(selectState);
        if(selectState==true) {
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//div[@class='css-76zvg2 r-homxoj r-ubezar r-1ozqkpa'])[2]]")).click();
            System.out.println("If condition");
        } else {
            radioElement.click();
            System.out.println("Else condition");
        }
```

Attaching HTML code of Radio button.

```
<div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1d09ksm r-1inuy60 r-1qxgc49" style="padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 0px;">
<div class="css-1dbjc4n"></div>
<div class="css-1dbjc4n">
    <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-18u37iz r-1w6e6rj">
        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1awozwy r-1loqt21 r-18u37iz r-117bsoe r-1otgn73" data-focusable="true" tabindex="0" data-testid="one-way-radio-button" style="margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-zso239">
                <svg data-testid="svg-img" viewBox="0 0 18 18" width="18" height="18" fill="#000" color="#000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="8" fill="#FFF" stroke="#F7941D" stroke-width="2"></circle>
                        <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="4" fill="#EDB16A"></circle>
                    </g>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n">
                <div class="css-76zvg2 r-homxoj r-ubezar r-1ozqkpa" dir="auto" style="font-family: inherit;">one way</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-1awozwy r-1loqt21 r-18u37iz r-117bsoe r-1otgn73" data-focusable="true" tabindex="0" data-testid="round-trip-radio-button" style="margin-right: 20px;">
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n r-zso239">
                <svg data-testid="svg-img" viewBox="0 0 18 18" width="18" height="18" fill="#000" color="#000" preserveAspectRatio="none">
                    <circle cx="9" cy="9" r="8" fill="#FFF" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-width="2"></circle>
                </svg>
            </div>
            <div class="css-1dbjc4n">
                <div class="css-76zvg2 r-homxoj r-ubezar r-1ozqkpa" dir="auto" style="font-family: inherit;">round trip</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share a link to the page you are working on?

Comment: There is no radiobutton tag, just circle -> https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_circle.asp

Comment: I'm working on spice Jet website. https://www.spicejet.com/

Comment: How to check if svg circle is selected or not?

Comment: _if "one way" checkbox is selected then the browser should select the two way check box_: Please [edit the question](/posts/73453853/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: For circle tag you can not check selected state bcs it has not such state. What you can is to get any attribute of any tag using `element.getAttribute("ATR name")`.

Comment: Is there any way we can check which circle is selected. Could you please elaborate on it as I'm new to it and don't know how to proceed. @pburgr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's code I'm likely to use repeatedly (like checking whether a radio button is selected or not), I like to put it in a method so it's easily reusable. This method takes the parent DIV of the radio button and counts the number of SVG circles inside. If there's more than one, the radio button is selected. This way you can use this method for not only the One Way radio button but any radio button on the page.

```
public static boolean isSelected(By locator) {
    return new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(locator)).findElements(By.cssSelector("circle")).size() > 1;
}
```

Simple examples

```
By oneWayLocator = By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='one-way-radio-button']");
By roundTripLocator = By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='round-trip-radio-button']");
boolean oneWaySelected = isSelected(oneWayLocator);
boolean roundTripSelected = isSelected(roundTripLocator);
```

It sounds like you want to check to see if the One Way radio button is selected and if so, select Round Trip instead. To do that,

```
By oneWayLocator = By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='one-way-radio-button']");
By roundTripLocator = By.cssSelector("div[data-testid='round-trip-radio-button']");

if (isSelected(oneWayLocator)) {
    driver.findElement(roundTripLocator).click();
}
```

I declare driver as a property of the page object class so that I don't have to pass it around in all of my methods, e.g.

```
public class HomePage {
    WebDriver driver;
    ...

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }
```

and then create an instance of the class while passing in the driver from my main/test method.

```
HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where should I declare driver in this case. I've created the method below my main class. Since driver is declared in my main class hence when I try to run this code it shows error as declare driver method.

Comment: @RohitMathur I've added the driver declaration code

Answer (score -1):

Most important thing a circle tag represents the one circle, not the svg tag. So svg tag which looks like selected radiobutton contains two circle tags.

You can measure number of circle tags in svg tag and based on that consider the svg as un/selected.

**Code:**

```
    List<WebElement> svgTags = driver.findElements(By.tagName("svg"));
    for (WebElement svgTag: svgTags) {
        int circlesCount = svgTag.findElements(By.tagName("circle")).size();
        if (circlesCount == 1) {
            System.out.println("looks like unselected radiobutton");
        }
        else if (circlesCount > 1) {
            System.out.println("looks like selected radiobutton");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("no circle in svg");
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
looks like selected radiobutton
looks like unselected radiobutton
```

Comment: With your locators you are picking up every single SVG tag on the page, looping through them, and printing whether they are selected or not. There are 29 SVGs on the page.

Comment: Then adjust the locator by your needs.

Comment: I've used this code but circle count size is 0 in this case.